# Having issue with using jQuery pushy js in two menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using https://github.com/christophery/pushy on my site.
The problem is I have two separate pushy menus. Now while one menu item is expanded and I try to open menu item from other menu, the first menu item collapses.

[image: This is menu item from 1st menu opened]

[image: This is 2nd menu opened]

[image: This is the problem, the menu item opened from 2nd menu collapses menu item from 1st menu]

Comment: The one who downvoted, mind telling what's the issue?

Comment: the issue is: you need to create a minimal example for us where we can reproduce your problem. and don't link to other sites, post the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using bootstrap collapse for the 1st menu.